# Custom terminal as VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-extensions

Can a VSC extension add an entry in the "New Terminal" menu and pipe args into Python or some other terminal program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are examples available on the VSC samples repository:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/terminal-sample/src/extension.ts
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/pull/449/files